# In "The Hobbit", where did goblins come from?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit

I was wondering if goblins were somehow just created like humans and elves, or if they were a cross-breed of some other creatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Tolkien, before the movies, Orcs and Goblins were not different creatures:

> Orc is not an English word. It occurs in one or two places [in *The Hobbit*] but is usually translated goblin (or hobgoblin for the larger kinds).
> —J.R.R. Tolkien, Preface to *The Hobbit*

Quoted from [The One Wiki to Rule Them All](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Goblin).

The history of the Orcs is the real thing you need to look at.